# Applying regex between two dataframes efficiently

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a bit of a performance issue while trying to match two specific words in two dataframes. I need to return a 1 for every row containing a word and else a 0. The function I wrote looks as follows:

```
def matchWords(row):
    row = row[0].upper()
    for x in df_X.Names:
        if re.search("\\b" + x + "\\b", row):
            return 1
    return 0
```

This function is called from a lambda and although it works fine, it takes quite a long time to run. I have allready applied multithreading in an effort to increase the speed but I want it faster. Is there a way to maybe precompile the `df_X.Names` or does anybody have another tip to get this faster / more efficient?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No idea where you have `df_X.Names`, but it can be used to prep a regex like `Name1|Name2`, etc. like `re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format("|".join(df_X.Names)))` and then use this regex to search a row.

Comment: This is roughly what I wanted to do but this way I get a unicodeEncodeError because the `df_X` dataframe has entries from many different languages (Greek, Chinese, English, etc)

Comment: What is your Python version? 2.x? Then you need to use `u""` prefex everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), multiple words can be `join` by `|` (`or`). Last use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'d': {0: 'wa', 1: 'rs', 2: 'qn'}, 
                   'e': {0: 'i', 1: 'r', 2: 't'}, 
                   'f': {0: 'a', 1: 's', 2: 'f'}})
print df1
    d  e  f
0  wa  i  a
1  rs  r  s
2  qn  t  f

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 'wa ug dh', 1: 'rs sd qn', 2: 'ga mf rn'}, 
                   'c': {0: 'i', 1: 'r', 2: 't'}, 
                   'b': {0: 'a', 1: 's', 2: 'f'}})
print df
          a  b  c
0  wa ug dh  a  i
1  rs sd qn  s  r
2  ga mf rn  f  t
```

Join values from column `d` with separator `|`:

```
words = "|".join(df1.d.tolist())
print words
wa|rs|qn

print df.a.str.contains(words)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

print np.where(df.a.str.contains(words), 1, 0)
[1 1 0]

df['new'] = np.where(df.a.str.contains(words), 1, 0)
print df
          a  b  c  new
0  wa ug dh  a  i    1
1  rs sd qn  s  r    1
2  ga mf rn  f  t    0
```